# Histogram is not starting at the right min even filter added

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

#### The Mapping

```
          "eventTime": {
            "type": "long"
          },
```

#### The Query

```
POST some_indices/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
            "range": {                   
              "eventTime": {
                "from": 1563120000000,
                "to": 1565712000000,
                "format": "epoch_millis"
              }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
      "min_eventTime": { "min" : { "field": "eventTime"} }, 
      "max_eventTime": { "max" : { "field": "eventTime"} }, 
      "time_series": {
        "histogram": {
          "field": "eventTime",
          "interval": 86400000, 
          "min_doc_count" : 0,
          "extended_bounds": {            
            "min": 1563120000000,
            "max": 1565712000000
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

#### The Response

```
"aggregations": {
    "max_eventTime": {
      "value": 1565539199997
    },
    "min_eventTime": {
      "value": 1564934400000
    },
    "time_series": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1563062400000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key": 1563148800000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
        ...
```

#### Question

As the reference clearly mentioned

> For filtering buckets, one should nest the histogram aggregation under a range filter aggregation with the appropriate from/to settings.

I set the filter properly (as the [demo](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count) does) and the `min` and `max` is also providing the evidence.

But why still the **first** `key` is *SMALLER THAN* than the *from* (or min_eventTime)?

So weird and I totally get lost now ;(

Any advice will be appreciated ;)

#### References

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked out a solution for now, but I kind of think it's a bug in Elastic Search.

I am using [`date_histogram`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#_offset) instead though the field itself is a long type and via `offset` I moved the starting point forward to the right timestamp.

```
  "aggs": {
    "time_series": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "eventTime",
        "interval": 86400000,
        "offset": "+16h",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": 1563120000000,
          "max": 1565712000000
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "order_amount_total": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "order_amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

#### Updated

Thanks for the help of @Val, I re-think about it and have a test as follows:

```
    @Test
    public void testComputation() {
        System.out.println(1563120000000L  % 86400000L); // 57600000
        System.out.println(1563062400000L  % 86400000L); // 0
    }
```

I want to quote from the doc

> With extended_bounds setting, you now can "force" the histogram aggregation to start building buckets [on a specific min value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count) and also keep on building buckets up to a max value (even if there are no documents anymore). Using extended_bounds only makes sense when min_doc_count is 0 (the empty buckets will never be returned if min_doc_count is greater than 0).

But I believe the `specific min value` should be one of `0, interval, 2 * interval, 3 * interval, ....` instead of a random value as I used in the question.

So basically in my case, I could use `offset` of histogram to solve the issue as follows.

<sub>I don't actually need date_histogram at all.</sub>

```
       "histogram": {
          "field": "eventTime",
          "interval": 86400000, 
          "offset": 57600000,
          "min_doc_count" : 0,
          "extended_bounds": {            
            "min": 1563120000000,
            "max": 1565712000000
          }
        }
```

---

A clear explanation posted by Elastic Search member @polyfractal (thank you for the detailed crystal explanation) is also proving the same logic, more details could be found [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/45595#issuecomment-521665322).

A reason for the design I want to quote here:

> if we cut the aggregation off right at the extended_bounds.min/max, we would generate buckets that are not the full interval and that would break many assumptions about how the histogram works.

Comment: It's not a bug, `1563120000000` resolves to `14.07.2019 at 18:00:00`. Since your histogram interval is set to one day (i.e. 86400000), the min bound is rounded to the beginning of 14.07.2019 (i.e. 1563062400000). The fact that you give an offset of +16h does the trick, but it would be better that your field be a `date` field so that in your `date_histogram` aggregation you can specify your [timezone](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#_timezone).

Comment: @Val thanks for the help, really appreciate it ;) I give a second thought, I think you are right. I updated the answer which I believe clears out my confusion. Thank you for the help ;)